# Keystrokes Delayed or Missing in SketchUP Under Wine

Tags: keyboard, wine, shortcut-keys, 15.10

I am trying to use SketchUp 2016 Make under Wine 1.7.

Keystrokes seem to be delayed or missing. For example after choosing the Move/Copy tool, pressing the Ctrl key to invoke the Copy function sometimes works immediately, sometimes it has to be pressed several times or holding it for several seconds before the + sign emerges.

Same for selecting elements and hitting the Delete key. Sometimes it works, sometimes the same annoying behavior.

Ubuntu version is 15.10.

Thanks for considering.

Comment: Do you play games? Is there such a problem, or is it specific to only this app? If you have no such a problem anywhere else, then I think it could be caused perhaps by some partially *(or not at all)* implemented function *(ofc it's just a guesswork)*, then I'd advice you to update to [wine 1.8](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and check if the problem persists. If it's still there, consider filling a bug.

Comment: Btw, searching about delays gives [this blogpost about SketchUp](http://wiredrevolution.com/wine/fix-sketchup-refresh-bug-linux-wine). Check if that help, and consider filling a bug anyway — perhaps some other apps would benefit of it too.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, can you consider posting the comment as an answer? There is at least one person finding your comment useful and it's possible you can reach more if you do post it as answer.

Comment: @jokerdino okay, I did. Actually, I saw their answer, and even upvoted it — it's okay, I'm fine with reputation points ☺ Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you play games? Is there such a problem, or is it specific to only this app? If you have no such a problem anywhere else, then most probably it is caused by a partially *(or not at all)* implemented function — then I'd advice you to [update to wine 1.8](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and check if the problem persists. If it's still there, consider filling a bug.

Comment: Finally upgrading to wine1.8 did the trick, Thank you. I fooled around with several versions of wine up to 1.7. I even had an installation on a different system under wine1.6, where the file load/save issue mentioned in a now missing answer arose. Wine1.8 lead to well functioning SketchUp on both boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after installing SketchUp the shortcuts did not work (wine 1.7.x and 1.8.0). I solved it by resetting all shortcuts in the SketchUp shortcuts menu (Window - Preferences - Shortcuts - Reset all).

Grtz

Answer (score 1):

I am using wine 1.8 ubuntu 14.04 and sketchup 2016 64bit. I had loads of trouble getting keyboard input to work properly for shortcuts. I had to hit a key multiple times or hold it down so it repeats.  I changed the windows version to 10 in wine configure for sketchup and it now works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my other post I inadvertently ignored the first rule of fault finding, only change one thing at a time. Ubuntu 14.04 wine 1.8 sketchup 2016. Shortcuts called by keyboard strokes stop working reliably when the default tray in sketchup is brought up with the instructor enabled. The workaround is to disable the instructor in the tray selector menu. Something in the instructor is messing with the keyboard focus. After doing this you need to restart sketchup to make keystrokes work again.

Comment: Then please delete the previous one.

Comment: Android Dev if I could find how to do this I would. David Forester although the original question seems to already have been answered my solution addresses the same problem that may be being experienced by other users and is entirely valid. I can reliably create and solve the problem.

Comment: Right I see your problem now, shortcuts are called by keystrokes. I could have made that clearer but this was written for sketchup users.

Answer (score -2):

I reset all my keyboard shortcuts didn't work. I changed my default to windows 8 in my wineprefix now everything works great. sketchup 2016 wine 1.9.5  xenial 16.04 Ubuntumate.